# Angular unit-testing $logProvider configuration

Tags: angularjs

What I'm doing it wrong? I want to test $logProvider but it seems that application have not configurate on inject...

```
"use strict";

var $log$;

describe("logProvider", () => {

    var prov;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app',($logProvider)=>{
        spyOn($logProvider,'debugEnabled');
        prov = $logProvider;
    }));

    beforeEach(inject((_$log_) => { }));

    it("should be defined", () => {
        expect(prov.debugEnabled).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
    });

});
```

My config for log provider.

```
export function logProvider($logProvider){
    'ngInject';

    $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);

}
```

And the error:

```
  PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0)
Expected spy debugEnabled to have been called with [  ] but it was never called.
```

Comment: Use `toHaveBeenCalled();` instead.

Comment: It does not matter since function is never called.